# Get selected items of menubutton

Tags: javafx, menuitem

I have 3 MenuButtons in my JavaFX-Application, each one filled with CheckMenuItems. 
I want to get the Text of **every** selected Item of the MenuButton. How shall i proceed?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all `MenuItems`, filter selected and map them to `String`.

```
MenuButton mb = new MenuButton();
mb.getItems().addAll(new CheckMenuItem("One"), new CheckMenuItem("Two"), new CheckMenuItem("Three"));
mb.getItems().stream().forEach((MenuItem menuItem) -> menuItem.setOnAction(ev -> {
    final List<String> selectedItems = mb.getItems().stream()
            .filter(item -> CheckMenuItem.class.isInstance(item) && CheckMenuItem.class.cast(item).isSelected())
            .map(MenuItem::getText)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(selectedItems);
}));
```